# Sorting an array based on first digit of property

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array based on the first digit encountered in the title.

My attempt was replacing the non-numeric characters with '' (title.replace(/\D/g, ''). It gives me back the digits but I'm not sure how to sort the array from this point.

So, test0 first followed by test1, test2 and test3.

```
model = [
  {
    "title": "test3"
  },
  {
    "title": "test1"
  },
  {
    "title": "test2"
  },
  {
    "title": "test0"
  }
];
```

Comment: Closely related: [Sorting an array of JavaScript objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects) and [Sorting objects in an array by a field value in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sorting-objects-in-an-array-by-a-field-value-in-javascript). You already know how to transform the field to your liking, so simply perform that transformation on the field in your comparison function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can your use regex within Javascript's `sort` function, like the following.

```
var model = [
    {
        "title": "test3"
    },
    {
        "title": "test1"
    },
    {
        "title": "test2"
    },
    {
        "title": "test0"
    }
];
```

## Update:

As Danilo Valente stated in comments, if your integer begins with a `0`, you need to extract the first `0` from the string. Since `02 => 0`

```
model.sort(function (a, b) {
    //Strips out alpha characters
    a = a.title.replace(/\D/g, '');
    b = b.title.replace(/\D/g, '');

    //sets value of a/b to the first zero, if value beings with zero.
    //otherwise, use the whole integer.
    a = a[0] == '0' ? +a[0] : +a;
    b = b[0] == '0' ? +b[0] : +b;

    return a - b;
});
```

Comment: He wants to sort based on the first digit, but in your case if we had `"title02"` it would appear after `"test1"`.

Comment: @DaniloValente Ah, yes. Thanks for pointing that out! I updated my code to cast `a` and `b` as integers.

Comment: First you have to extract only the first digit so `02 => 0` and then compare both: `0 < 1`.

Comment: @DaniloValente I tested the updated code before I posted it, and it sorted properly for me.

Comment: I did too, and it still doesn't work. Replace `"test0"` with `"test02"` and you'll see. The result should be `["test02", "test1", "test2", "test3"]`, but instead it returns `["test1", "test2", "test02", "test3"]`.

Comment: @DaniloValente oh, I see what you mean now! That was a derp on my end, it "looked" correct when I ran it :) I'll update my code appropriately.

Answer (score 4):

```js
var model = [{
  "title": "test3"
}, {
  "title": "test1"
}, {
  "title": "test2"
}, {
  "title": "test02"
}, {
  "title": "test0"
}];

// pass a custom sort fn to `.sort()`
var sortedModel = model.sort(function(a, b) {
  // just get the first digit
  return a.title.match(/\d/) - b.title.match(/\d/);
});

console.log(sortedModel);

// [ { title: 'test02' },
//   { title: 'test0' },
//   { title: 'test1' },
//   { title: 'test2' },
//   { title: 'test3' } ]
```

Comment: He wants to sort based on the first digit, but in your case if we had `"title02"` it would appear after `"test1"`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to sort based only on first digit, you can call `.sort` with a custom function and then use a simple regex to find the first digit:

```
model.sort(function (a, b) {
    var da = a.title.match(/\d/);
    var db = b.title.match(/\d/);
    return parseInt(da) - parseInt(db);
});
```